# How to use let! within a seq {} block in F# and yield result

Tags: f#

I need to figure out how to use `let!` within a seq.

**Note**: this is part of an async function and the matchTransaction function is async as well.

```
let matchedTransactions 
    = seq {
            for cardTransactionWithOrder in cardTransactionswithOrder do
                let! matchedTranaction = matchTransaction(page,bnzBatch,cardTransactionWithOrder)
                yield! matchedTranaction
    }
```

I get the error below which doesn't really match what I am doing because matchTranaction function returns a record (specific type) not a collection.

> Error FS0795  The use of 'let! x = coll' in sequence expressions is not permitted. Use 'for x in coll' instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matchedTransaction` is of type `Async<'a>`. You can construct a `seq` of those async calls and end up with a `Async<'a> seq`, which you can then obtain the await results for with `Async.Parallel`.

The error you're facing is that you're trying to use `Async's` `let!` inside of a `seq` computational expression. The compiler assumes you're trying to use `Seq's` `let!` instead.

```fs
let matchedTransactions = // Async<'a []>, if this is inside of an async {} block, you can use let! here

    let matchedTransactionsAsync = // seq<Async<'a>>
        seq { for cardTransactionWithOrder in cardTransactionswithOrder do
                  matchTransaction(page,bnzBatch,cardTransactionWithOrder) }

    matchedTransactionsAsync |> Async.Parallel // Async<'a []>
```